# Jenkins selenium unable to find the firefox profile

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins

My test always look for a specific Firefox profile that I have created. Below is what I have defined in spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :my_firefox_driver do |app|
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => "RSPEC")
end
```

It works like a charm when it's not running under jenkins.

However, it creates problem when I started to integrate my test into jenkins. It seems to not able to locate the firefox profile. Below are the errors:

> sign up new user with existing domain (FAILED - 1)
>
> An error occurred in an after hook
>       Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to find profile named: "RSPEC"
>       occurred at /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.46.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:99:in
>   `fetch_profile'

Can someone advise what probably i have missed?

Comment: Hi Evan, this code looks odd. In the 2nd line you are creating a new FF profile  - which is not being used, since you are passing a profile 'RSPEC' in the third line (which I believe exists for your user profile where you execute tests).  fFirefox profiles are created per user basis. So when it is running under jenkins, its trying to find the 'RSPEC' in <jenkins user's home directory>/.mozilla/firefox/profiles/<profile_name>, which doesn't exist. Hence the error. If you need a profile with presets, you'll need to create it as the jenkins user first, and then re-use it in tests.